# Getting thumbnails on a single line in CSS

Tags: css, blogger

I have been trying to get the thumbnails into one horizontal line for my blogger post. I read about the CSS display property and changed it from `block` to `inline` but it is not working.

```
<style type='text/css'>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400italic);
* { margin: 0; }
body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif; 
} 
dl#simple-gallery { 
  position: relative;
 /* background: #222; */
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
}
dl#simple-gallery dt{
  width: 12.5%;
  min-width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
dl#simple-gallery dt img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
dl#simple-gallery dt:hover+dd, dl#simple-gallery dt:focus+dd { 
  opacity:1;
}
dl#simple-gallery dd { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 22%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s opacity;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
dl#simple-gallery dd img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display:inline;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

</style>
```

I'm using this HTML

```
<dl id="simple-gallery">
<dt tabindex="1"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/london-thumb.jpg" alt>
<dd><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/london.jpg" alt>Westminster Bridge at dusk, London
<dt tabindex="2"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/paris-thumb.jpg" alt>
<dd><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/paris.jpg" alt>The Eiffel tower, Paris
<dt tabindex="2"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/san-francisco-thumb.jpg" alt>
<dd><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/san-francisco.jpg" alt>Golden Gate bridge at sunset, San Francisco
</dl>
```

Comment: Did you try making a container div? Then all elements inside the container div are float: left;? Then you can set the width for those thumbnails to something like width: 33.3% if there are 3 of them, etc.

Comment: It does have a container like thing, I'm not very sure of it.. I'm a complete noob at CSS `http://demosthenes.info/blog/58/CSS-and-Images-Simple-Roll-over-Image-Gallery`

Comment: Can you add a fiddle with your current code in it? http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you referring to the HTML ?

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/7x4dxmwd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified the CSS for the point of showing you exactly how to perform layout. You will need to add in all the other functionality; but this will show you how it is done.

I also added the -webkit transition prefix for browser compatibility.

http://jsfiddle.net/qyka6qo2/2/

```
#simple-gallery dt {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#simple-gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#simple-gallery dd {
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   -webkit-transition: .7s opacity;
   transition: .7s opacity;
   opacity: 0;
} 

dl#simple-gallery dt:hover+dd, dl#simple-gallery dt:focus+dd { 
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were after: http://jsfiddle.net/zeh4jnL4/

I added a `float:left` (as suggested by Termato) to `dl#simple-gallery dt` and moved the image pop-up down a bit more from `3em` to `7em` to make more space.

The final CSS looks like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400italic);
* { margin: 0; }
body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif; 
} 
dl#simple-gallery { 
  position: relative;
 /* background: #222; */
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
}
dl#simple-gallery dt{
  width: 12.5%;
  min-width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float:left;
}
dl#simple-gallery dt img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
dl#simple-gallery dt:hover+dd, dl#simple-gallery dt:focus+dd { 
  opacity:1;
}
dl#simple-gallery dd { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 7rem;
  left: 22%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s opacity;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
dl#simple-gallery dd img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display:inline;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```